# Better battery for a Galaxy S4 Mini?

Tags: smartphones, android

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini phone, and the stock battery doesn't usually last me the full day. Do 3rd party batteries work well? Is there any battery that has a longer life than the stock battery?

Comment: Are you on your phone a lot during the day? Would making the phone physically bigger be ok with you? What are your goals for the new battery? What is your budget? Would you please edit your question to include the answers to these questions?

Comment: I have a Galaxy S3 Mini with a 3rd party battery and works perfect. The battery is 2680 mAh so I can work with the mobile about a day and half without charge it. It is almost the same size of the stock battery.

Comment: There are a lot of third party batteries on Amazon. I picked one up for my Galaxy s5 that is made by Anker. The battery(7500 mAh) usually lasts me about 2 full days with frequent use. It came with its own case as well. Just be prepared to have a bigger phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, if you care about the battery life then look at the number of mAh the replacement battery has. The Samsung original battery for Galaxy S4 Mini is 1900 mAh so you want something higher, e.g. [Zerolemon Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini 5100mAh](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IK3EECE). Beware that some batteries are too thick to fit in the original phone case, so they come with a thicker case. Also, there exist a bunch of applications that help detecting which applications take the most of your battery, you might want to optimize on the software side as well.